# Type error in tensorflow probability binomial

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, apple-m1, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to run a model using tensorflow-probability on an Apple M1 (I've successfully run other tensorflow models on this computer, but I mention the architecture in case it's part of the issue). I have the following model code where berndfs is a dictionary that contains two pandas dataframes for each value of 's', one containing the sample and one containing survey data:

```
def tfdmrp_run():
    n_chains = 4
    dtype = tf.float32
    berndfs = load_tfdmrp_datacache()
    shortnames = list(berndfs.keys())
    
    sample = berndfs[s]['svy']
    age_shape = len(berndfs[s]['census'].agecat.unique())
    gender_shape = len(berndfs[s]['census'].sex.unique())
    edu_shape = len(berndfs[s]['census'].educat.unique())
    counts = sample['count'].values.tolist()
    agecatlist = sample.agecat.values.tolist()
    genderlist = sample.gender.values.tolist()
    edulist = sample.educat.values.tolist()

    modlist = [
        tfd.HalfNormal(1),
        lambda sigma_age: tfd.Sample(tfd.Normal(0,sigma_age),sample_shape=age_shape),
        tfd.HalfNormal(1),
        lambda sigma_gender: tfd.Sample(tfd.Normal(0,sigma_gender),sample_shape=gender_shape),
        tfd.HalfNormal(1),
        lambda sigma_edu: tfd.Sample(tfd.Normal(0,sigma_edu),sample_shape=edu_shape),
        tfd.Normal(0,1), #intercept
        lambda intercept,coef_edu,a,coef_gender,b,coef_age: tfd.Independent(
            tfd.Binomial(
                total_count=tf.cast(counts,tf.int32),
                logits=intercept
                + tf.squeeze(tf.gather(coef_age, tf.cast(agecatlist,tf.int32),axis=-1))
                + tf.squeeze(tf.gather(coef_gender,tf.cast(genderlist,tf.int32),axis=-1))
                + tf.squeeze(tf.gather(coef_edu,tf.cast(edulist,tf.int32),axis=-1))
            ),
            reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1
        )
    ]

    model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(modlist)
    model.resolve_graph()
```

The code returns the following error at the call to resolve_graph():

```
*** TypeError: Found incompatible dtypes, <class 'numpy.int32'> and <class 'numpy.float32'>. Seen so far: [<class 'numpy.int32'>, <class 'numpy.float32'>, ...]
```

I get the same error if I try to call sample. I'm completely stuck because at this point no inputs to the model are in anything other than a native python datatype. I'm using tensorflow-macos version 2.10.0, tensorflow-probability version 0.18.0, and numpy version 1.23.3. All of the dependency lists I can find suggest that there shouldn't be any compatibility issues. Does anyone know what could be causing this and/or how to fix it?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/Documents/Projects/repos/rutracker/dmrp/dmrptfp.py", line 124, in tfdmrp_run
    model.resolve_graph()
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_sequential.py", line 460, in resolve_graph
    distribution_names = self._flat_resolve_names(
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_sequential.py", line 473, in _flat_resolve_names
    for d in self._get_single_sample_distributions()]
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution.py", line 353, in _get_single_sample_distributions
    ds = self._execute_model(
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution.py", line 1045, in _execute_model
    d = gen.send(next_value)
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_sequential.py", line 399, in _model_coroutine
    dist = dist_fn(*xs)
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_sequential.py", line 610, in dist_fn_wrapped
    return dist_fn(*reversed(xs[-len(args):]))
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/Documents/Projects/repos/rutracker/dmrp/dmrptfp.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    tfd.Binomial(
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/distribution.py", line 342, in wrapped_init
    default_init(self_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/binomial.py", line 371, in __init__
    dtype = dtype_util.common_dtype([total_count, logits, probs], tf.float32)
  File "/Users/jacobtucker/miniconda3/envs/tfdmrp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/internal/dtype_util.py", line 104, in common_dtype
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Found incompatible dtypes, <class 'numpy.int32'> and <class 'numpy.float32'>. Seen so far: [<class 'numpy.int32'>, <class 'numpy.float32'>, ...]
```

Comment: A single line from an error does not mean anything without context, you should include the complete traceback in the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks! I just added the full traceback to the question text.

Comment: The documentation says that both parameters that you are passing to tfd.Binomial should be floating point values, not integers: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Binomial

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you!! That was the problem - I just needed to cast the count variable to a float instead of an int.

Comment: Good, maybe you can edit the title and text, as you see it was not an error related to numpy or using a M1 processor.